# Error upload image in Android app -- Api Foursquare

Tags: java, android, foursquare, image-upload

I am developing an Android application in which users can upload photos of venues you visit. I'm using the endpoints and have begun testing https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/PHOTO_ID through Apigee console. The problem I have is that if I send an image via the console returns me an error 400 problems with mime type as you can in this still image is correct, I think. 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9uUMZ3ZVbl_bG5rOUNhM01wb2M/edit?usp=sharing (console error)
I have also tried uploading through the application I am developing and I returned the same error. The execute method in the app is as follows:

```
        TokenStore tokenStore=new TokenStore(getApplicationContext());
        String token=tokenStore.getSavedToken();

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = params[0];

        String urlServer = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add?public=1&venueId=5252da418bbd79f3aaa70ae6&oauth_token="+token;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        try  {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
            //outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("serverResponse", "serverresponse "+ serverResponseMessage);
            Log.i("serverResponseCode", "serverResponseCode "+ serverResponseCode);


            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();



        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        //Exception handling
        }
```

In my tests online server, upload the image class works fine so the problem must be with some kind of data that does not put right for the Foursquare API. Anyone have experience with this? thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact error you're seeing? I'm not too familiar with the library you're using to make HTTP requests; are you formulating that correctly? Why are you setting the `Content-Type` header twice? As per the [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add), it should be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Have you tried with mime type Application/Octet-Stream ?